# if $x^a+y^a<m$,then $x^b+y^b<n$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to prove :Let x,y>0 n>0, for what values of m such that if $x^a+y^a<m$,then $x^b+y^b<n$ And a, b are arbitrary positive real numbers. I am wondering if I need to discuss into cases.

Comment: any information about $n$ and $m$ which is bigger, $a$ and $b$ !

Comment: m,n can be any positive real numbers and I want to discuss both cases: when a>b and when a<b.

Comment: so , we are given $a,b,m$ then need to give best value for $n$ which makes sure that $x^b+y^b < n$ ?, please make the question more clear.

Comment: No. We are fixing a,b,m and we want to find m to satisfy the second inequality above.

Answer (score 0):

Without further information: Given that $x^a+y^a < m$ then $x^b+y^b < 2 max(x,y)^b <n$

is Given by $n = 2 m^{\frac{b}{a}}$

the idea is that $\lim \limits_{a \to \infty} (x^a+y^a)^{\frac{1}{a}} = max(x,y)$

For example : $x^3+y^3<100$ then $x^5+y^5 < 4308.87$.

Other than that, we need more information.